# Apache Beam Python wordcount example errors on Windows10

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am running Anaconda - conda virtual env with Python 2.7
I have followed Apache Beam Python SDK Quickstart 
When I run -

```
'python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount --input C:\Users\simon_6dagkya\OneDrive\ProgrammingCore\Apache Beam\examples\wordcount\kinglear.txt --output C:\Users\simon_6dagkya\OneDrive\ProgrammingCore\Apache Beam\examples\wordcount\output.txt'
```

I get following error:

```
INFO:root:Missing pipeline option (runner). Executing pipeline using the default runner: DirectRunner.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\simon_6dagkya\Anaconda3\envs\apachebeam\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\simon_6dagkya\Anaconda3\envs\apachebeam\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Users\simon_6dagkya\Anaconda3\envs\apachebeam\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\examples\wordcount.py", line 136, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Users\simon_6dagkya\Anaconda3\envs\apachebeam\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\examples\wordcount.py", line 90, in run
    lines = p | 'read' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input)
  File "C:\Users\simon_6dagkya\Anaconda3\envs\apachebeam\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\io\textio.py", line 524, in __init__
    skip_header_lines=skip_header_lines)
  File "C:\Users\simon_6dagkya\Anaconda3\envs\apachebeam\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\io\textio.py", line 119, in __init__
    validate=validate)
  File "C:\Users\simon_6dagkya\Anaconda3\envs\apachebeam\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\io\filebasedsource.py", line 121, in __init__
    self._validate()
  File "C:\Users\simon_6dagkya\Anaconda3\envs\apachebeam\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\options\value_provider.py", line 133, in _f
    return fnc(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\simon_6dagkya\Anaconda3\envs\apachebeam\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\io\filebasedsource.py", line 181, in _validate
    'No files found based on the file pattern %s' % pattern)
IOError: No files found based on the file pattern C:\Users\simon_6dagkya\OneDrive\ProgrammingCore\Apache
```

Any help most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`IOError: No files found based on the file pattern C:\Users\simon_6dagkya\OneDrive\ProgrammingCore\Apache`

Your input string has a space in it. Add quotes.